# Ordering publication list in thesis

Tags: thesis

When including a list of own publications in thesis, which order would you follow?

- Descending chronological order
- Ascending author position
- Relevance to thesis chapters
- (Any other ways)

Comment: Are these publications being cited in the thesis?

Comment: Look if standard is in place at your institution. If it is about your own publications in the CV section I personally like the last at top, grouped by importance, full papers - proceedings - posters...

Comment: @mmeent Some are cited

Comment: @Alchimista Yes, I was thinking something like this. Thank you for sharing your experience/ preference :)

Comment: What is your goal, in including publications which are *not* cited?

Comment: @mmeent As Alchimista pointed out, I would like to include them along with cited ones on a page as part of my work during my PhD study, but those are side projects irrelevant to the topic discussed within the thesis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look for published papers in your field and do it like they do. Different fields have different conventions, try to follow what is common in your area. Your advisor should also be able to tell you what is usually done in your field.

Comment: Thanks. That's true and planned to do these as well

Answer (score 1):

This might be field-dependent, but in electrical engineering it is common to sort references according to the order in which they are cited in the thesis. You might want to look at published theses in your field and see how they do it.

Comment: Thanks. I looked for a number of theses and people seem to have different preferences, but would like to ask for more opinions.